# Currying template and match it with the template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, currying

I have a class `Receive` which has a template template parameter. It is non variadic so a class template with different parameters number cannot match. I consider that if the parameters of a template is greater than `Receive`'s template template parameter has. I can use currying to reduce the parameters so that `Receive` can accept it. I thought it's an easy job at first. I defined a struct `Curry`.

```cpp
template <template <typename...> class C, typename FirstArg>
struct Curry {
  template <typename... Args>
  using result = C<FirstArg, Args...>;
};
```

And I have these codes for testing

```cpp
template <template <typename> class>
struct Receive1 {};

template <template <typename, typename> class>
struct Receive2 {};

template <template <typename, typename, typename> class>
struct Receive3 {};

template <typename, typename, typename>
struct Test {};
```

Since `Test` has three template parameters, I thought it can match the `Receive1` after curry it twice. But then I got a compile error.

```cpp
template <typename Tp>
using Alias = Curry<Curry<Test, void>::result, void>::result<Tp>;

int main() {
  Receive1<Alias>{}; // OK
  Receive1<Curry<Curry<Test, void>::result, void>::result>{}; // cannot compile
 
// test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
// test2.cpp:36:58: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<class> class<template-parameter-1-1> > struct Receive1’
//    Receive1<Curry<Curry<Test, void>::result, void>::result>{};
//                                                           ^
// test2.cpp:36:58: note:   expected a template of type ‘template<class> class<template-parameter-1-1>’, got ‘template<class ... Args> using result = Curry<Test, void>::result<void, Args ...>’
}
```

I felt strange because it can accept the `using` alias but refuse the origin. My gcc version is `gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)`. I try to add the `-std=c++17` and succeeded to compile. But things got weirder. The below snippet can be compiled too.

```cpp
  Receive1<Curry<Test, void>::result>{}; // Only 1 curried. Should has two paramters.
  Receive2<Curry<Curry<Test, void>::result, void>::result>{}; // 2 curried. Should only has one parameter.
  Receive3<Curry<Curry<Test, void>::result, void>::result>{}; // ditto
```

I don't know why it can be compiled under the argument `-std=c++17`. It doesn't make any sense. Does my codes make UB?

Answer (score 0):

Well after the more strugling I decided to abort the variadic template template parameter and instead define a struct for each number of parameters respectively. It needs repeated codes and is not a real generic solution.

```cpp
#define TP_(arg) typename arg
#define CONCAT_(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define CURRY_(N, _1, params, args)                           \
  template <template <_1, params> class C, typename FirstArg> \
  struct Curry##N {                                           \
    template <params>                                         \
    using result = C<FirstArg, args>;                         \
  };                                                          \
  template <template <_1, params> class C, typename Arg>      \
  constexpr auto Curry()->Curry##N<C, Arg>;

template <template <typename _1> class C, typename FirstArg>
struct Curry1 {
  using result = C<FirstArg>;
};
template <template <typename _1> class C, typename Arg>
constexpr auto Curry() -> Curry1<C, Arg>;

#define CURRY_2_(arg1, arg2) CURRY_(2, TP_(arg1), TP_(arg2), arg2)
#define CURRY_3_(arg1, arg2, arg3) CURRY_(3, TP_(arg1), CONCAT_(TP_(arg2), TP_(arg3)), CONCAT_(arg2, arg3))
#define CURRY_4_(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) \
  CURRY_(4, TP_(arg1), CONCAT_(TP_(arg2), TP_(arg3), TP_(arg4)), CONCAT_(arg2, arg3, arg4))

CURRY_2_(_1, _2)
CURRY_3_(_1, _2, _3)
CURRY_4_(_1, _2, _3, _4)

#define CURRY(Class, Arg) decltype(Curry<Class, Arg>())::result
```

This snippet defines `CURRY` for the templates with 1 to 4 parameters. And it can work as my expect.

```cpp
  Receive1<CURRY(CURRY(Test, void), void)>{};
  Receive2<CURRY(Test, void)>{};
  Receive3<Test>{};
```

But I still don't know why the codes in my question description have such weired behaviors.